# Array converted to int

Tags: php, arrays, database, integer, redbean

I have a problem, I need to convert from an array to a full number, but I don't understand how. i`m using redbeanphp. Help please

`print_r(R::getRow('SELECT SUM(view) FROM posts WHERE author LIKE ? LIMIT 1', ['dffdfghdfgdf']));`

Result:
Array ( [SUM(view)] => 27 )

if through echo, then it simply gives an error that it is an array.

Result:
Warning: Array to string conversion in

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should print the value of the array element, not the array itself.

Also, you may use an alias for a result column using the `as` operator.

```
$result = R::getRow('SELECT SUM(view) as s FROM posts WHERE author LIKE ? LIMIT 1', ['dffdfghdfgdf']);
print_r($result['s']);
```

`echo` would work either in this case.